# Converting .htaccess to nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) p.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

How would I change that to work with nginx?

Also, where do I place it?

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name site.com www.site.com;
        root /home/site/public_html;

        location / {
            root   /home/site/public_html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
                proxy_pass http://www.site.com;
                proxy_cache my-cache;
                proxy_cache_valid  200 302  60m;
                proxy_cache_valid  404      1m;
                location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
                        expires 30d;
                }
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /home/site/public_html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `try_files`?

Comment: what is try_files?

Answer (score 0):

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

.. from `Example for Drupal/FastCGI`